# PHP Emails with PHP Mailer

Tags: php, html, email

I'm creating a form that sends an email to the email that was entered into it. I have installed PHP mailer on my server.

Currently when sending emails via PHP they send like this:
[image: Example of look.]

All emails sent are via the hosting server when I'd like them to look like this.

[image: Example of expected look]

Just like any other email sent on the domain they should be mailed by `domain.com` rather than the server.

I'm just testing this so using a simple form as a proof of concept.

```html
<form method="post" name="process.php" action="process.php">
<p>Name:</p><br><input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
<p>Email Address:</p><br><input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

I'm then using this PHP to send the email:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'noreply@domain.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';

$email_from = "noreply@domain.com";
$email_subject = "Test Email";

$to = $email;
$headers = "From: noreply@domain.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: noreply@domain.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: me@domain.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";


$email_body = <<<EOM
<p color="#000000">Hello, $name.<br><br> This is a test email for mailing from the domain rather than the server.<br><br> </p>
EOM
    ;

mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

?>
```

Basically, I want PHP emails mailed by my domain and I don't know how to do this so any help would be appreciated, my web host doesn't seem able to help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

`UPDATE`

This code for the form.

```html
<h1>The email gets sent to a bookings address.</h1>

<form method="post" name="process.php" action="process.php">
<p class= "whitetextsubsmall">Name:</p><br><input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
<p class= "whitetextsubsmall">Email Address:</p><br><input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

And this code for `process.php`

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'noreply@domain.com'; /* This is the sender of the bookings. */
$mail->Password = 'password';


$mail->setFrom('noreply@domain.com');
$mail->addAddress('bookings@domain.com', 'Company Bookings');
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name); /* Reply to the user who submitted the form from the bookings email. */
$mail->Subject = 'Booking Request Test';

$mail->isHTML(TRUE);
$mail->Body = 'Message test <br> Booking Request from: $name <br><br> Email: $email.';

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh please do not accept an email address from user input. Spammers will hijack your form in under 10 min.

Comment: @AlexBarker It needs user emails in order to send confirmations.

Comment: The code sends emails using the built in `mail` function, not the PHPMailer library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the PHPMailer syntax with PHP mail() syntax.

For the PHPMailer, use the following in your code.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'noreply@domain.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';

/* Set the mail sender. */
   $mail->setFrom($email, $name);

/* Add a recipient. */
   $mail->addAddress('noreply@domain.com', 'earningtoanimate');

/* Add a replyto. */
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);

/* Add a CC and Bcc. */
$mail->addCC('noreply2@domain.com', 'earningtoanimate2');
$mail->addBCC('noreply3@domain.com', 'earningtoanimate3');

/* Add email subject. */
$mail->Subject = 'Test Email';

/* Add email body. */
$mail->isHTML(TRUE);
$mail->Body = 'There goes your message.';

/* Finally send the mail. */
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

Test the above and give your feedback. Note, I didn't test code. Just wrote them here so it's possible to have some edits if need be.

For further reading visit [PHPMailer documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps)

Comment: That threw a 500 error. Also, you seem to have the input mixed up. The sender is the noreply address not the inputs @OmniPotens

Comment: Sorry about my mix up. Fix that. Let us now be concerned with your 500 error. Can I see your exact codes so I can see what could be wrong?

Comment: I need the email to be sent from our noreply address to our bookings address mailed by the domain and not the server. It should tell the bookings address the name of the sender and their email @OmniPotens

Comment: I thought you were to update with your current codes so I can be of more help? Can you create a chat and send me the link let's be more direct if you don't want to flood here with much back and forth responses? Note also that I provided you with inline comments in my code to assist you set the right values. Read the document I referenced for additional guide and you should get what you want running without much ado.

Comment: Never got your response after messaging you. I will continue here instead. Looking at this "require 'vendor/autoload.php';" can you verify that you have this autoload.php file or are you just requiring it without having it?